# "no implicit reference conversion" even though conversion is defined

Tags: c#, generics, interface, type-conversion, covariance

I have written the following piece of code in an attempt to provide a type-safe interface:

```cs
namespace MWE
{
    public abstract class C {}
    public class A : C {}
    public class B : C {}

    public class Container<T> where T : C
    {
        public readonly T Value;

        public static implicit operator T(Container<C> c)
        {
            return c.Value;
        }
    }

    public interface IWrapper<out TC> where TC : C {}

    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(IWrapper<Container<C>> wrapper) {}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile. The `Container<C>`-part of the `wrapper` parameter to the `Foo` constructor causes the compiler to produce the following error:

> The type 'MFE.Container<MFE.C>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TC' in the generic type or method 'IWrapper<TC>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MFE.Container<MFE.C>' to 'MFE.C'.
> The type 'MFE.Container<MFE.C>' must be convertible to 'WeirdTestStuff.C' in order to use it as parameter 'TC' in the generic interface 'MFE.IWrapper<out TC>'.

I can't figure out where the problem is exactly, since the Covariance for the conversion seems to be there and there is even an implicit conversion from a `Container<T>` to `T` defined. Since `T : C`, I assumed it should just work like this.

I'd like to keep `Foo`'s constructor as is if possible.

I hope someone can point me to a solution of this problem

Comment: Since `C` is already a base class is it acceptable that `Container<T> : C where T : C`? And also change implicit operator to `T(Container<T> c)`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not acceptable; `Container<T>` can't be extend / implement `C`. I think you mean `C(Container<T> c)`.

Answer (score 3):

> even an implicit conversion from a Container to T defined

That is true but that's not what the compiler requires. It requires:

> implicit *reference* conversion

(My *emphasis*)

An implicit reference conversion is not one supplied by any user-defined operator and is allowed only when one type derives (directly or via intermediate types) from the other<sup>1</sup>.

`Container` *has-a* `C` and can be converted to a `C` via a user-defined operator but that's not enough to make it *be-a* C. Your question is too abstracted to say what the fix should be here - should `Container` be non-generic and derived from `C`? That's the obvious way to "shut up" the compiler but may not solve your actual problem.

You can't use generics to make a type's base-type settable at runtime.

---

<sup>1</sup>These are Eric Lippert's [Representation-preserving conversions](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The point I was missing is the fact that reference conversions don't take my conversion into account.
True, I kept the MFE relatively generic. In my case Container can't be derived from `C`. My implementation of the Container rather works like a `Union<A, B, C>` to some extend with `A` and `B` extending some abstract class `C` and `Union<A, B, C>` containing some object of `A` or `B` as some instance extending the base class `C`. Therefor the less beautiful way of fixing my specific problem is using something like `Union<IWrap<A>, IWrap<B>, IWrap<C>>`.

Comment: The key point here is that user-defined conversions are *never* classified as reference conversions, and that's what covariance requires. However, any reference conversion will do, even ones that do not directly involve inheritance relationships. For example, if we have `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` we can convert that to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>` even though there is no inheritance relationship between `IE<string>` and `IE<object>`.  Of course there is an inheritance relationship between `string` and `object`.

Comment: The question of whether representation-preserving conversions that are *not* reference conversions should work with variance is a tricky one, and the CLR is inconsistent on this point. `uint` to `int` is representation-preserving, and an `uint[]` is convertible to both `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<uint>` in the CLR, but `(IEnumerable<int>)M();` where we have `IEnumerable<uint> M() { yield break; }` is *not* legal in the CLR.

Comment: @EricLippert - to avoid having to add too many caveats, do you think just changing "allowed only" to "typically"? If I made such a change, I'd welcome an additional footnote that digs into the details if you could suggest some text/create a new blog post :-)

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't worry about it too much. The vast majority of the time the conversions just work the way you'd expect them to, which was our goal in creating the feature in the first place. The small details of how exactly it works are of importance to the spec writers and the implementation team; I mention them just to be complete.