# Delegate 'RequestDelegate' does not take 2 arguments - ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, minimal-apis, asp.net-core-8

This is my Minimal API (.NET 8):

```
app.MapPost("check", async ([FromBody] UserClaims claims, ApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    var result = await dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Phone == claims.Phone);

    if (result is null)
        return TypedResults.NotFound();

    return TypedResults.Ok();
});
```

[image]

I am getting a [CS1593](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1593?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1593)) error under my lambda expression.

What am I doing wrong ?

Removing the following part from my API solves the problem:

```
if (result is null)
    return TypedResults.NotFound();
```

Also, replacing `TypedResults` with `Results` solves the problem.
Is there a restriction when using `TypedResults`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TypedResults docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typedresults-vs-results),

> To use TypedResults, the return type must be fully declared, which when asynchronous requires the Task<> wrapper.

```cs
app.MapPost("check", async Task<Results<Ok, NotFound>> ([FromBody] UserClaims claims, ApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    var result = await dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Phone == claims.Phone);

    if (result is null)
        return TypedResults.NotFound();

    return TypedResults.Ok();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 3):

While you can specify the delegate return type I would argue that switching to [`Results`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results?view=aspnetcore-8.0) would be easier (as you discovered):

```
app.MapPost("check", async ([FromBody] UserClaims claims, ApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    // ...

    if (result is null)
        return Results.NotFound();

    return Results.Ok();
});
```

Both return the same type - `IResult` so the compiler can infer correct return type.

Also in this particular case you can use ternary operator. If you want to keep the `TypedResults` it can reduce clutter a bit. For example with `IResult` (though arguably not much reason to do so):

```
app.MapPost("check", async ([FromBody] UserClaims claims, ApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    // ...

    return result is null 
        ? (IResult)TypedResults.NotFound() 
        : TypedResults.Ok();
});
```

Or `Results<NotFound, Ok>`:

```
app.MapPost("check", async ([FromBody] UserClaims claims, ApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
{
    var result = claims;

    return result is null 
        ? (Results<NotFound, Ok>) TypedResults.NotFound() 
        : TypedResults.Ok();
});
```

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77654460/2501279) and discussions in the comments.